# MySQL: set field to position in order by clause

Tags: mysql, ranking

I'm designing a leader-board where we display each users ranking along with their *change in ranking* from the previous day.  The ranking is found by simply ordering the users by the `points` column.

To find the change in ranking from the previous day, I'm thinking I'll have to have a cron job that stores the users rank every day at midnight.

Is it possible to write this cron job to use only one sql query? I need to design a query that stores every user's rank in the `previousRank` column.  Any help?  I'd like to do this in a constant amount of queries, not needing to process each row with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion:

Create a `previous_points` column and then issue this simple query each night:

```
UPDATE table SET previous_points = points;
```

Then to display ranks by the current or previous day, simply use `points` or `previous_points`, respectively.

**Edit**

You could use temporary tables to make use of this data.

Here is an example:

1: Make a temporary table populated with today's rankings:

```
SET @rank := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ranks_today
    (id INT(8), rank INT(6), previous_rank INT(6))
    SELECT id, @rank:= @rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM users
    ORDER BY points DESC;
```

2: A temporary table for yesterday's rankings:

```
SET @rank := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ranks_yesterday
    (id INT(8), rank INT(6))
    SELECT id, @rank:= @rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM users
    ORDER BY previous_points DESC;
```

3: Now we'll copy yesterday's rankings to today's table for convenience:

```
UPDATE ranks_today, ranks_yesterday
SET ranks_today.previous_rank = ranks_yesterday.rank
WHERE ranks_today.id = ranks_yesterday.id;
```

4: Finally, a query that shows the user's name, ranks for today and yesterday as well as the change:

```
SELECT u.name, t.rank, t.previous_rank, t.previous_rank - t.rank `change`
FROM ranks_today t, users u
WHERE u.id = t.id;
```

You could optionally create `rank` and `previous_rank` columns in your users table if you want and update those in step 3.

Here is sample output from the query:

```
name        rank    previous_rank    change
----        ----    -------------    ------
Fred        1       2                1
Betty       2       5                3
Barney      3       3                0
Bam Bam     4       1                -3
Wilma       5       4                -1
```

Comment: good thought, but not quite what I want: I don't need the ability efficiently display the rank from the previous day, but I need the ability to efficiently display the current rank along with the "change in rank" from the previous day.

Comment: @all how you going to handle when multiple users having same points?

Comment: Users with the same point value adds a small spanner to the works, the OP will have to decide what order they should be ranked. One solution when calculating ranks is to add additional columns to the `ORDER BY` clause, so that ranking is determined by more than points alone. (i.e. `ORDER BY points, last_name...` or `ORDER BY points, most_recent_points_awarded_datetime...`)

Comment: This seems pretty close to the solution.  Temporary tables only last for one session however.. Why use temporary tables however?  It does not seem efficient.. I cant be creating temporary tables every time I need to fetch this ranking data for the end user

Comment: You can use temporary tables to create the rankings and populate your users table once per day. If the points change and you want to re-rank more often than that, you may want to create such tables on the fly. Mostly it just depends on how "live" you want the data to be.